# jQuery mouseenter function not triggering on element included in ext HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, include, mouseenter

I have a file "including.html" where I use Javascript to include HTML from an external file "includesecondfile.html.

```
including.html
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>
<title>My First Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="including.css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery       /jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>  
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
</head>

<body>
<h1>My Web Page, I'm H1</h1>
<p>First P element. Welcome to my web page.  Here you'll find all sorts  of information about me.</p>
<h2>My Books second H2 element</h2>

<div id="menu"> </div>

<p>You can find information on my books here as well.</p>


<script> 
    $(function(){
      $('#menu').load('includesecondfile.html'); 
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("h1").mouseenter(
            function(){
                $('h1').css('background-color', 'yellow');
            }
        );
        $("h1").mouseleave(
            function(){
                $('h1').css('background-color', 'white');
            }
        );      
    });
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the contents of includesecondfile.html

```
<hr>
<h1>Second file H1 element</h1>
<p>Here it is yo man secon paragraph element</p>
<h2>Second H2 element</h2>
<hr>
```

When I look at this in the browser, the elements from the includesecondfile.html are displayed correctly, h1, h2 and p all show correctly.
The second piece of javascript works when I mouse over the H1 element from including.html but not when I mouse over the H1 element imported from includesecondfile.html. The strange thing is that the CSS is affected on the h1s from both files. i.e. both h1's backgrounds turn yellow when I mouseover the h1 element from the main file but neither turn yellow when I mouseover the h1 element from the included file. 
How can I make the background change to yellow when I mouseover the included file's h1 element too?

Comment: Looks like the extra HTML is loading asynchronously, so the event handler is bound *before* it loads. There are fixes for that, *but*, why don't you do the hover colour changes just in CSS? You don't need JS for it.

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn, it was as you said. I moved the JS to the includesecondfile.html and it all worked. I'm just writing this to learn about JS so the above are just test files to play with it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like you can make a class with the properties and use the toggleClass() method on mouseenter, mouseleave.